# partial fraction decomposition and balancing rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the following equation:

```
4/(x(x + 2))
```

The first step is simple. Just split the denominator into its linear terms and since we have linear terms in the denominator, we know the numerators will be a constant, A and B:

```
A/x + B/(x + 2)
```

Now to solve for A and B, we just find a common denominator and then add the rational expressions:

```
( A(x + 2) )/( x(x + 2) ) + Bx/( x(x + 2) )
( (A + B)x + 2A)/( x(x + 2) )
```

Since this equation is equal to the original and the denominators are the same, we can say the following:

```
( (A + B)x + 2A)/( x(x + 2) ) =  4/(x(x + 2))
```

And so we can say the numerators are equal:

```
(A + B)x + 2A = 4
```

At this point, everything is clear. The equation is then solved like this:

```
 (A + B)x + 2A = 0x + 4
 A + B = 0
 2A = 4
 A = 2
 2 + B = 0
 B = -2
```

Well wait a second. How was I supposed to know to add a 0x in there? And more importantly why is it legal to do this:

```
A + B = 0
```

How do we know for sure that this cannot be true:

```
(A + B)x + 2A = 0
```

I don't understand how we can just pull pieces of an equation out like this and set them equal to each other. Whatever happened to the rule that both sides of the equation must be balanced (what you do to one you must do to the other)?

Comment: Because you are dealing with **identities** here: things have to be true for **all** $x$.

Comment: You have $(A+B)x + 2A = 4$ which _is the same thing_ as $(A+B)x + 2A = 0x + 4$ because $0x = 0$, so the equation is balanced (add $0$ to both sides). Equating coefficients on both sides of the equation implies $A+B = 0$ as your $x$ coefficient is $0$.

Comment: When I come across another equation like this in the future, is there specific clues to know to add in the 0x. Remember the 0x was added and not part the equation.

Comment: I suggest practicing partial fractions over and over until the concept becomes clear to you. It is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say that $(A+B)x+2A=4$ is equivalent to $(A+B)x+2A=0x+4$, we have not unbalanced the equation.  We've added $0x$ to on side. But $0x=0$, and addig $0$ to anything doesn't change it.

Comment: Honestly if I didn't know the answer, I would have never added in the 0x. What is the clue to add in the 0x? To set the coefficients equal to each other and the constant terms equal to each other in order to create a system of two linear equations to find two unknowns?

Comment: Well, you have an equation which says that two polynomials are equal to one another. This can only happen when the coefficients of the corresponding terms are equal to one another. Since, the left hand side has an $x$ term, we need to have an $x$ term on the other side to match up with.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to go through this much of trouble in finding the coefficients $A, B$ of $${4 \over x(x+2)} = {A \over x} + {B  \over (x+2)}$$

look at the behavior of ${4 \over x(x+2)}$ for $x$ close to 0, i.e. $x = 0+\cdots$ it behaves like
 $${4 \over x(\cdots+2)} = {2 \over x} + \cdots$$  so  that gives $A = 2.$

now to find $B$ we look at ${4 \over x(x+2)}$ for $x = -2 + \cdots$ 
$${4 \over (x+2)(-2+\cdots)} = { -2\over (x+2)} + \cdots$$  so  tha gives $B = -2.$

so we have $${4 \over x(x+2)} = {2 \over x} - {2  \over (x+2)}$$